# how to use phonegap spinner dialog plugin for cordova 2.9

Tags: html, cordova, spinner, phonegap-plugins

Hello i am creating an app using phone/cordova, on pgb build, and for the platform of android, my problem is i am making use of a plugin thats shows a loading spinner, while a page loads.,
i have got it to work on phonegap/cordova 3, but unable to get it to work on phonegap 2.9.0 and etc.

here is a link to the phonegap plugin

https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog/blob/8556cc0bbed322344e03a4caee4c51f4155acef0/README.md

is there anyone who has successfully used this plugin for cordova 2.9.0
Regards

Comment: Try using these 2.9.0 compatible new plugins [SpinnerDialog](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/747) and [SpinnerPlugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/721)

Comment: i tried using the plugin for 2.9.0, but when i added this "<gap:plugin name="it.mobimentum.phonegapspinnerplugin" version="1.1.0" />" in  my config it kept on giving me a build error." geez ur build failed", is there any particular way of using the plugin with cordova 2.9.0, do u have a sample for 2.9.0, thanks

Comment: i tried using the plugin for 2.9.0, but when i added this "<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.spinnerdialog" version="0.2.1" />" in my config it kept on giving me a build error." geez ur build failed", is there any particular way of using the plugin with cordova 2.9.0, do u have a sample for 2.9.0, thanks

Comment: See the last threads of [this post](https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog/issues/2)

Comment: phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/Paldom/SpinnerDialog.git didnt work, it refused to get the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why downgrade to a lower version in the first place?

I just used the plugin for my app on iOS and instead of `show()` and `hide()` used:

`cordova.exec(null, null, 'SpinnerDialog', 'show', ['Ehi', 'You']);`

but a further twist I found is just directly calling this didn't work but wrapping it up in a function worked well:

```
window.showSpinner() = function(){
    cordova.exec(null, null, 'SpinnerDialog', 'show', ['Ehi', 'You']);
};
```

The `window.` simply makes the function globally accessible. For hide just change the show to hide.